# Received wrong frame data with ExtractMpegFramesTest in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to get frames by using `MediaCodec` and found ExtractMpegFramesTest.java example from this site http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ . I could save the frames but it looks a little weird. I don't really know what was wrong with it. Maybe color space?

Here is the frame: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxhKRYTBr4adMGJ1aWhHNjdHUDg/edit?usp=sharing

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Things worked well if the video resolution is 480x360 with Gadmei tablet. If it's bigger, I will get similar results as above (green screen with part of the frame). Is this the limitation of `MediaCodec` or the example that I was working on?

**Edit 2:**

It worked fine with big resolution 1920x1080 on Nexus 7. Maybe it is the problem of the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what resolution produces bad output on what device?

you can look at: [Android: MediaCodec: bad video generated on Nexus for 480x480 while 640x640 works well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490578/android-mediacodec-bad-video-generated-on-nexus-for-480x480-while-640x640-work/24506997)

may be you have the same issue